# Mongoose findOne() callback returns null when ID is passed in

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Working with mongoose's findOne() to return an object in mongo that exists. The findOne() always returns null when the ID I use is passed in. 
I'm not sure how to explain it, so here are examples of when it does and does not work:

This is my main function:

```
function main() 
{
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    pullOneDoc(db, '639438443613851600');
}
```

The following below are the findOne() queries being used, however one works while the other does not.

This function works correctly and successfully returns the "ret" entry and prints it on the screen.

```
function pullOneDoc(db, value)
{
    console.log(value);
    db.collection('Tweet').findOne({id:639442211910717400},function (err, ret) {
     console.log(ret);
     if(err) console.log('error: ',err);
    });
}
```

This code below however does not return 'ret' as a doc, but always returns null. The console.log for "value" shows that the number is exactly the same, except just not hardcoded in.

```
function pullOneDoc(db, value)
{
    console.log(value);
    db.collection('Tweet').findOne({id:value},function (err, ret){
     console.log(ret);
     if(err) console.log('error: ',err);
   });
}
```

Checking mongo itself (using the findOne function in mongo), I can successfully find the ID, so I know it's there.
What exactly is causing one to work but not the other? I understand that javascript is asnyc, however the value in the console log shows that the value is passed in correctly. I have tried if statements saying if(value!=null), then execute the query however that has also not worked.

Thanks!

**Solved**
I should just not pass in anything as a String if I'm looking for an Int ID type

```
pullOneDoc(db, 639438443613851600) //Without 'quotes'
```

Comment: What's the id data type? It looks like in the working example you are passing in an integer id and in the other it's a string?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the id type is an int. I have tried parseInt(value) to turn it into an int with the same result*

Comment: Where are you parsing it? Can you please [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32378849/edit) your question to add those salient details?

Comment: I feel like a moron, that worked. I didn't even think that would be a problem. Thanks alot